# How to split string with (\)?

Tags: c#, split

How to split this string:

```
var array= str.Split(@"\"); //error  cannot convert from 'string' to 'char'
```

Thank you!

Comment: `Split` has several overloads. The ones which accept a `string` expect a second parameter of type `StringSplitOptions`. See complete list here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx

Comment: Additional note: If you want to split a `string` by a `string` instead of a `char`, use `str.Split(new string[] { "\\" }, StringSplitOptions.None);`

Comment: `str.Split(new Char[]{'\'});`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a single quote instead, because `Split` method accepts a `char` as single parameter, not a `String`

`var array = str.Split('\\');`

Comment: Split method has overloads that accept also strings

Comment: @Steve Already editted the answer, it does accept Strings, but not without  (at least) a second parameter

Comment: Actually, `Split` method takes `string[]` or `char[]` as a parameters but single `char` is implicitly convertable to `char[]` as a single item but  `string` can't :)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation @SonerGönül, you're absolutely right! Feel free to edit the answer, if needed. :)